# Is the following get / reset pair thread safe in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please look at the following code:

```cs
public sealed class Foo<T> : IDisposable
    where T : IDisposable, new()
{
    public T Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        var oldBar = _bar;
        using (oldBar)
        {
            _bar = new T();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // TODO:
    }

    private T _bar = new T();
}
```

Consider multithreaded environment. `Bar` getter and `Reset` method are being called from multiple threads. Is it guaranteed that client would never get a disposed `T` object via `Bar` property? `Foo` object is guaranteed not to be disposed at that moment. If not, how to get it right? I want to use low-lock techniques if possible.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thank you all guys for the help. The question need to be clarified. I want

1. `Foo` to manage `Bar` state;
2. to be sure that clients will not use disposed `T` object.

It seems that it is impossible with the code provided before. Here is the code that reflects my needs:

```
public sealed class Foo<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class, IDisposable, new()
{
    public bool TryExecute(Action<T> action)
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_bar == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            action(_bar);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_bar == null)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(string.Empty);
            }

            Reset(new T());
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_bar != null)
            {
                Reset(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Reset(T newBar)
    {
        var oldBar = _bar;
        using (oldBar)
        {
            _bar = newBar;
        }
    }

    private T _bar = new T();
    private readonly object _sync = new object();
}
```

I beleive it is thread safe this time.

Comment: Without showing how it will be used, we can't answer your question. Also you deleted out `oldBar.Dispose();` from `Reset` method. Is it done delivberately?

Comment: Writing thread-safe code is very hard. Writing thread-safe code that doesn't use locks is next to impossible. I would write one that does it correctly with locks first, then later on see if this introduces a performance issue that needs to be fixed. My guess is it won't.

Comment: Without *some* kind of synchronization code, it will not be possible to guarantee what you ask.

Comment: I have realized that there is actually no way to get it right with the API design provided.. Client would cash reference to T and there is no way to unsure that it will not use it after Dispose.

Comment: @alpinsky you need to clarify what you want to do. It *is* possible to make `Reset()` thread-safe without using locks. This has *nothing* to do with ensuring the clients get a `Bar` isn't disposed. Perhaps you shouldn't even care about this - do you really want to eagerly dispose `Bar`?

Comment: You can make `Reset()` thread-safe without locks but you can't prevent clients from storing a reference to a previous T instance. I suggest you convert the `Bar` property to a factory method that returns a cached instance. This way it's the client's responsibility to dispose T

Comment: The main obstacle is the need to eagerly dispose `T`. Is that a real need? Unless T contains unmanaged resources or database connections, you don't have to dispose it immediately. Managing a cached DTO is far easier than managing a "smart" DTO that contains connections or service proxies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get all of the requirements, but at least you can make `Reset` itself thread-safe without locks. As it is, it can fail because multiple concurrent calls could try to dispose the same object.

You can't prevent clients from storing a reference to a previous T instance.

What you *can* do, is ensure that only one `Reset` call can change the stored value at a time, using  [Interlocked.CompareExchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb297966(v=vs.110).aspx). This would also allow one of the calls to dispose the old value. The original code would fail because all concurrent calls could attempt to dispose the same old value. With `CompareExchange` we can swap new and old values atomically :

```
public void Reset()
{
    var originalValue=_bar;
    var replaced=Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _bar,new T(),originalValue);
    if(replaced!=_bar)
    {
        //We got to replace the value, 
        //we could dispose it safely if we wanted to

        if (replaced!=null) 
        {
           replaced.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The comparison to `oldValue` means that even if two threads execute `Reset` concurrently, only one of them will be allowed to assign to `_bar` and be able to dispose the old value. The other will see that `_bar` has a new value.

This doesn't solve the problem of multiple temporary objects and anyway, we don't want to dispose.

It would be easier if `Reset` accepted a parameter with the replacement value so it didn't have to create the new objects itself.

```
public void Reset(T newValue)
{
    var originalValue=_bar;
    var replaced=Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _bar,newValue,originalValue);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would say use _bar variable via Bar property only, do not use it directly. Put a lock on set property on Bar. Code as follows:

```
 public sealed class Foo<T> : IDisposable
    where T : IDisposable, new()
{
   private readOnly object key;

    public Foo(){
      key = new Object();
      this.Bar = new T();
    }

    public T Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        private set { 
        lock(key){
           _bar = value;
        }
      }
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        var oldBar = _bar;
        this.Bar = new T();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Bar = null;
    }

    private T _bar;
}
```

Comment: Please comment before voting it down.

Comment: First, the OP's asked for low-lock techniques. Second, using the field directly or through a property shouldn't matter - except in this case, doing so will result in *two* attempts to get the same lock. This code will deadlock.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question *Consider multithreaded environment. Bar getter and Reset method are being called from multiple threads. Is it guaranteed that client would never get a disposed T object via Bar property?* Also, your code is no improvement whatsoever.

Comment: Oh yes two locks can result in deadlock. I removed one. Check would it work now? And without lock its not possible.

Comment: Locking the setter isn't the problem - reference assignments are already atomic

Comment: No, it can never be guaranteed that client will never get a disposed T object via Bar property.

Comment: Max. he can intimate client that the object has been disposed via Bar getter property.